# Computing the expected value of the product of two discrete variables

Tags: probability, correlation

I didn't know why I compute $E(XY)$ wrongly.
$$X=(1, 2, 0.5, -1),\qquad Y=(-2, 1, -0.5, 2).$$

$$E(XY) = \frac{-2 + 2 -0.25 -2}{4} = -0.5625\text{ (incorrect)}$$

because $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=-0.8542$, $E(X)=0.625$, $E(Y)=0.125$ so $E(XY)$ should be $-0.1042$.

Comment: What are the probabilities that X=x from (1,2,0.5, -1) and for Y? Are they all 1/4

Comment: Is this a sample of four paired observations?

Comment: Yap, it's as your saying. They are uniformly distributed and prob. is 1/4.

Comment: In order to compute E[XY] you should know the probabilities P(X=x, Y=y). Otherwise you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

$X=1$ and $Y=-2$ gives $XY=-2$

$X=1$ and $Y=1$ gives $XY=1$

Repeat this for every pair $(X,Y)$ to find all outcomes.
Average them over the total number to find $E(XY)$.

I think there's a way to compute it without calculating all the pairs, but this calculation is how $E(XY)$ is defined.

For the calculation, I would use $Cor(XY)+E(X)E(Y)=E(XY)$.

Comment: My computation is the same as your description I thought. The values of Cov(X,Y) and E(X) and E(Y) are absolutely correct because the software computed them. Only the E(XY) which computed by hand is wrong but didn't manage to find the reason.

Comment: The first part of my reply describes the correct way to compute E(XY) which is different from how you computed E(XY). In the way I described the calculation you should have 16 pairs to multiply, sum and average.

Comment: [Go to minute 4 of this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CrRJ86p7yg)